# Efficiently calculate values based on subsets of a list

Tags: trees

Let's say I have a list of items, each of which has some value
Eg. L1 = [A, B, C, ...]

And another list of items L2: [1, 2, 3, ...]. Each of the items in L2 needs to calculate the max value of a subset of the items in L1
Eg. Item 1 wants max(A,B,C) , item 2 wants max (D,E,F) , etc.

**I cannot figure out how to calculate all these values efficiently.**

I initially thought of using dynamic programming so that, after 1 calculates max(A,B,C), we store it in a hash table to save time when another item wants the max of the same subset (A,B,C), but I've just realized that it is theoretically possible to have a worst case where every item in L2 wants the max of a unique subset of elements in L1.

For example, using the combinations formula

```
Combinations(n,r) = n! / r! / (n-r)!
```

If L1 has 10 items (`n`), and each item in L2 wants the max of a unique subset of 5 items (`r`) of L1, that's already 252 possible combinations, giving me an exponential time algorithm!

**So, is there some existing algorithm to efficiently calculate the values of all these unique subsets?**
I'm sure there's some algorithm that deals with this (something to do with trees, I think?), but I just can't recall it.

Comment: Are the subsets part of the input? If so, the naive algorithm that calculates the max element of a subset by scanning all its elements is optimal, because you have to read the subsets, which already costs $\Theta(\sum_{S\ :\ \text{subsets}}|S|)$ time.

Comment: @xskxzr Not exactly. Each item in L2 has a list of the string names of the items in L1 that it cares about. Eg. In L2, item 1 has a list ['A', 'B', 'C'], item 2 has a list ['D', 'E', 'F'].

So, I don't have to technically read in each subset, I just have to read in the NAMES of the subset elements, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @xskxzr Also, surely there's some way to save time like this:
Eg. I want max(A, B, C, D): Naive approach is to scan each of those 4 elements but, if I've already previously calculated max(A,B,C) then I can just do one comparison between that previous max and D -- I can't quite figure out how I would make an algorithm out of that though.